# selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Chrome version must be between 70 and 73

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I am unable to user `selenium` with chrome webdriver as of this month. 
I see the following error :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message session not created: Chrome version must be between 70 and 73
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615355
```

My chrome driver is here :

```
chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.68
```

Comment: What version of Chrome?  V74? if so, then you need https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=74.0.3729.6/

Answer (score 0):

Your ChromeDriver v73.0.3683.68 would support Chrome (Browser) between 71~73. Probably your browser has got updated to v74.

If you are using Chrome version 74, please download **ChromeDriver 74.0.3729.6**

Comment: Confirmed copying downloaded file from here https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads resolves problem.